# Find the physical location of a MAC address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, iphone, phone

I want to find the physical location of a device, of which I only know its WiFi or Bluetooth MAC address. It is either an iPhone or Android phone. The device is not connected to a WiFi network, and is not connected to a Bluetooth device. I know the approximate location of the device (with a margin of error of about +-500 ft), but I would like to find the exact location of the device (and who is holding it) with a margin of error of at most +-1 ft. It was suggested I use RSSI to find the device (walking around with an antenna while scanning), but I have very little information as of how to capture the RSSI signal and figure out the source MAC address. I was wondering is this could be done through the device's PNL (preferred network list), and if the source MAC would be visible in the the PNL packets, as well as how to capture the packets. Thank you!

Comment: When I've tried the "walking around" method with a laptop doing an 802.11 monitor mode packet trace and looking at the RSSIs of all of the target Wi-Fi MAC address's transmissions, I could usually only narrow it down to two adjacent 10'x10' offices, if I didn't have access to the offices. I might have done better if I had a directional antenna.

Comment: In most cases the MAC Address cannot be used to identify a device outside of your own network, since in most cases, the MAC address isn't pushed outside of the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the device broadcasts its coordinates (unlikely), you're not going to locate it that way. About the best you can do is use the signal strength to determine if you've gotten closer or further. There's a hobby revolving around this sort of thing, a sort of [electronic fox hunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmitter_hunting). If you have multiple receivers within range of the device, you might be able to use [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation) to pinpoint it. The idea is simple but implementation can get difficult as shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/signal-triangulation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889765/triangulation-algorithm-on-grid-with-signal-strength-c-sharp).

Comment: I think that GPS coordinates have a margin of error of about 100 feet.... As far as I know. I'd like to actually locate the person with the device. Thank you for your answer though!